# Can someone help me out with changing my invocation phrase?

Tags: actions-on-google

For a project that I'm working on that is in Alpha right now, I used to use an invocation ''talk to XXX''. Now that I want to deploy the Action to Beta, I want to change the invocation name/phrase as well. So I changed it to ''talk to YYY'', which is the suggested input field in the simulator as well. But when I want to test this in the simulator, I get the following error message:

> Invocation Error:
>       You cannot use standard Google Assistant features in the Simulator. If you want to try them, use Google Assistant on your phone or other compatible devices.

For some reason, if I ignore the suggested input chip (which says ''talk to YYY'') and type in ''talk to XXX'' (the old invocation phrase) everything still works though. Seems that I'm missing something and Google support can't answer me, does someone know what I can do to successfully deploy to Beta?

Answer (score 0):

When I get that message, it's usually a problem with the Console. A refresh of the page—and sometimes a simple retry—usually does the trick.

You could also try "Change Version" to make sure you're pointed to "Draft".

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! I tried both disabling/re-enabling testing, as well as changing versions and changing back again, ánd refreshing the simulator a couple of times. Nothing seems to work, and the old invocation phrase is still the only way to get a proper response :( Anything else you could think of? Would be a great help!

Comment: Maybe make sure the language you're changing your invocation in and the language you're testing in match. Other than that, all I can think of is recreating the action from scratch. 